# i am using Selenium web driver and using chrome with with i want to set download location but failed

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
String desktopPath =System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\"+"Desktop";
String s = desktopPath.replace("\\","\\\\") ;

System.out.print(s);

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\WaqaeAbbas\\Downloads\\Compressed\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
String downloadFilepath = s;
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\Users\\WaqaeAbbas\\Desktop");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

options.addArguments("--test-type");

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);

cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);   

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Comment: Could you please add the error message?

Comment: no error but image not going to download on desktop

Comment: @Würgspaß image is not going to download on desktop

Answer (score 0):

It is not working if we give "\\". So, it is working when we pass download path as like this: 
String desktopPath ="C:/Users/WaqaeAbbas/Desktop";

Here is the updated code:

```
String desktopPath ="C:/Users/WaqaeAbbas/Desktop";
System.out.print(desktopPath);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\WaqaeAbbas\\Downloads\\Compressed\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
String downloadFilepath = desktopPath;
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory",downloadFilepath );

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--test-type");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);  
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Comment: not working again download go in download folder not in desktop

Comment: and if \\ is not work then how program find chrome driver path

Comment: The above code does not create any download folder, it will show the downloaded file on Desktop as we changed its default download location to desktop. it worked fine for me when I download a file from a site.

Comment: but on my laptop the file go to the download folder @radhikab

Comment: i also what this but download go to my default locaton

Comment: If possible, could you please share your code after updation. I will check and let you know